Force usage of software keystore
The android platform nowadays has a secure keystore, that is locked to the TEE (trusted execution environment) on phones where it is available. Notably, the TEE part is only used if the hardware supports it. This implies the existence of a software-backed keystore, that doesn't use a TEE. I've been able to confirm the validity of this notion, as on WayDroid on linux, /data/misc/keystore holds an actual keystore.
I'm an avid tinkerer, so I always have a bootloader unlocked/rooted phone, and I've hit a few situations where backing up apps and restoring them on a different phone, or even the same phone after wiping all the other data, has caused them to stop functioning, due to them being unable to decrypt the keys. This is an absolute deal breaker to me, as I strongly believe that my ability to own my data superseeds any means of security.
This is why, as there seemingly is no way to extract keys from a TEE, I'm looking for a way to force android to use a software keystore, such that /data/misc/keystore can be moved around to different phones and used to decrypt any apps. I want to do this through any means necessary, which includes the possibility of developing a magisk module or patching the ROM directly, in order to get this functionality. I just need to know where to look.
In the event where it matters, the ROM I'm currently using is crDroid, which integrates KernelSU as its root solution, rather than Magisk.

In my understanding using hardware security for keys tire or not is a compile option of AOSP. I would expect that regular Android ROMs don't contain the ability to store keys without it. Not sure if it is possible to replace the keymasterd and it's backend service with a pure software based version. https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/keystore#glossary

@Robert my question is based on the presumption that there already is a software implementation, I'm just looking for the logic that decides whether it's used or not.

Why should a ROM built for a device with hardware security contain the insecure code for a software based implementation? Keep in mind that Android is not a general purpose OS where all devices get the same software image. Every Android version is is a unique version adapted for a certain hardware regarding drivers, services, ...

@Robert Maybe not the built ROM, but I know for a fact that the ROM I'm using (crDroid, based on LineageOS) supports various different brands of phones including android emulators like WayDroid and the nintendo switch. The code for a software implementation should be there somewhere, likely in AOSP, with either build-time OR runtime logic for whether it's used or not, and I need to know what the logic is.

I am not sure if following will help you. I still try to understand why I have the issue, but it seems that a app I am using is trying to use the Hard-backed Keystore but somehow that's not possible and it refuses to login.
Tinkering around, I did find out that following bypassed it (maybe that's deactivating the Hard-backed Keystore) - my rom is using /data/misc/keystore too
Magiskpolicy deny gmscore_app keystore keystore_key gen_unique_id
chmod 660 /sys/fs/selinux/enforce
chmod 440 /sys/fs/selinux/policy #policy change not needed, just to make sure

First command denies the Google Play Service access to Keystore generating unique id, Which I assume is needed for the Keystore.
You can view the allowed list with: (and deny one by one to test or all with *)
magiskpolicy --print-rules | grep -E 'gms.*keystore|keystore.*gms'

If this may help on your problem, I can provide you the magisk module I made for this.
Link to my problem, maybe a solution will be found that helps you too.
Android Keystore error from GMS and NordVPN

Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I'll mess around with this idea, but unfortunately my ROM is using kernelsu rather than magisk. I can't find equivalent CLI tools in kernelsu, but maybe something like this would be possible, too?

Kernelsu is possible to run modules too, it looks like it uses same sepolicy.rule. You need to find the kernelsu Version for magiskpolicy. kernelsu.org/guide/difference-with-magisk.html
I can see a ksu_deny in the code. Maybe you can try in a shell if that works. github.com/tiann/KernelSU/blob/main/kernel/selinux/sepolicy.h
You can even run ksu and magisk together.
https://kernelsu.org/guide/faq.html#is-kernelsu-compatible-with-magisk

post-fs-data.sh:
`#!/system/bin/sh
MODDIR="${0%/}"
MODNAME="${MODDIR##/}"
MAGISKTMP="$(magisk --path)" || MAGISKTMP=/sbin
if [ ! -e "$MAGISKTMP/.magisk/mirror/sepolicy.rules/$MODNAME/sepolicy.rule" ] && [ ! -e "$MAGISKTMP/.magisk/sepolicy.rules/$MODNAME/sepolicy.rule" ]; then
magiskpolicy --live --apply "$MODDIR/sepolicy.rule"
fi`
This is the code i got out of a module. If you can't use magisk, you will need to find the ksu commands to do this.
